# Cannot allocate memory :Failed to create packet memory pool (rte_pktmbuf_pool_create failed) - for port_id 0

Tags: build, dpdk, meson-build, dpdk-pmd

I have upgraded DPDK from 17.02 to 21.11. RPM build was built and installed successfully. While running the custom application I saw the following error:

> Cannot allocate memory#012ms_dpdk::port::port: Failed to create packet memory pool (rte_pktmbuf_pool_create failed) - for port_id

Function call parameters : rte_pktmbuf_pool_create(port-0,267008,32,0,2176,0)

1. I have added std::string msg = rte_strerror(rte_errno); in error logs and it gives the output as
   **Cannot allocate memory**
2. LDD output shows the libraries are linked properly and there are no "no found" entries.

   ```
   ldd /opt/NETAwss/proxies/proxy | grep "buf"
           librte_mbuf.so.22 => /lib64/librte_mbuf.so.22 (0x00007f795873f000)

   ldd /opt/NETAwss/proxies/proxy | grep "pool"
           librte_mempool_ring.so.22 => /lib64/librte_mempool_ring.so.22 (0x00007f7a1da3f000)
           librte_mempool.so.22 => /lib64/librte_mempool.so.22 (0x00007f7a1da09000)
   ```
3. igb_uio is also loaded successfully.

   ```
   lsmod | grep uio

   igb_uio                 4190  1
   uio                     8202  3 igb_uio
   ```
4. cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
   512

   ```
   grep Huge /proc/meminfo

   AnonHugePages:    983040 kB

   ShmemHugePages:        0 kB

   HugePages_Total:     512

   HugePages_Free:      511

   HugePages_Rsvd:        0

   HugePages_Surp:        0

   Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
   ```
5. When I run dpdk-testpmd it seems to be working fine. Below is the output of the test application.

   ```
     ./dpdk-testpmd
    EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 2
    EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
    EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
    EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
    EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
    EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_vmxnet3 (15ad:7b0) device: 0000:13:00.0 (socket 0)
    TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
    testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_0>: n=155456, size=2176, socket=0
    testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc

    Warning! port-topology=paired and odd forward ports number, the last port will pair with itself.

    Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
    Port 0: 00:50:56:88:9A:43
    Checking link statuses...
    Done
    No commandline core given, start packet forwarding
    io packet forwarding - ports=1 - cores=1 - streams=1 - NUMA support enabled, MP allocation mode: native
    Logical Core 1 (socket 0) forwards packets on 1 streams:
      RX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) -> TX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) peer=02:00:00:00:00:00

      io packet forwarding packets/burst=32
      nb forwarding cores=1 - nb forwarding ports=1
      port 0: RX queue number: 1 Tx queue number: 1
        Rx offloads=0x0 Tx offloads=0x0
        RX queue: 0
          RX desc=0 - RX free threshold=0
          RX threshold registers: pthresh=0 hthresh=0  wthresh=0
          RX Offloads=0x0
        TX queue: 0
          TX desc=0 - TX free threshold=0
          TX threshold registers: pthresh=0 hthresh=0  wthresh=0
          TX offloads=0x0 - TX RS bit threshold=0
    Press enter to exit

    Telling cores to stop...
    Waiting for lcores to finish...

      ---------------------- Forward statistics for port 0  ----------------------
      RX-packets: 2              RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 2
      TX-packets: 2              TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 2
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

      +++++++++++++++ Accumulated forward statistics for all ports+++++++++++++++
      RX-packets: 2              RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 2
      TX-packets: 2              TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 2
      ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    Done.

    Stopping port 0...
    Stopping ports...
    Done

    Shutting down port 0...
    Closing ports...
    Port 0 is closed
    Done

    Bye...
   ```

I am not able to figure out the root cause of this error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I request you format and cleanup the information since it difficult to follow. From the question it is mentioned `there is a custom application where alloc is failed`. But in the logs `for testpmd testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_0>: n=155456, size=2176, socket=0`. Can you please share the information on huge pages (2MB or 1GB) and if root permission is used? Please post the logs of your application with `--log-level=8`.

Comment: @VipinVarghese PFB Huge page info  grep Huge /proc/meminfo

AnonHugePages: 983040 kB

ShmemHugePages: 0 kB

HugePages_Total: 512

HugePages_Free: 511

HugePages_Rsvd: 0

HugePages_Surp: 0

Hugepagesize: 2048 kB Unfortunately  I am not able to run that application independently. I also tried in other systems where we have dpdk version 17.02 but no luck. In another system, I am not seeing this issue. Whenever I am restarting the system I am seeing these error messages in /var/log/mail. The application is crashing because of rte_pktmbuf_pool_create memory issues.

Comment: ` I am not able to run that application independently. `, since the huge page is 2MB, `Whenever I am restarting the system I am seeing these error messages ` it looks like allocation of 2MB pages after restart is not happening quick enough. So what is ram size of the system and can you try allocating the huge page via grub (kernel cmdline)?

Comment: [root@ms ~]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        8161380 kB
MemFree:         4408536 kB
MemAvailable:    5425452 kB
Buffers:          400804 kB
Cached:           834204 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB

Comment: So for 8GB of memory, you request for 1Gb of huge page which is reasonable. So it seems like your `rc.init` scripts has delays for creating hugepage (I doubt if this is error). It is `really a shame your environment can not be debugged`. I am open for a live debug if you can share.

Comment: are there any updates from your ned for a live deug?

Comment: can you share the `eal args passed`. Based on the logs shared out of 512 page 1 2MB is used (not sure if this is custom app or testpmd). Pool Create requires more than `0.75GB` alone. Assuming minimum of 1Gb or more is required for custom. Since there are many new features like telemetry, fb_array, mp_process this might be requesting more memory than 1GB. A live debug can easily narrow down the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Memory allocation failure happens by moving from `DPDK 17.02 to 21.11`. This is expected for fixed 512 * 2MB and memory requirements from custom application.
2. DPDK 21.11 introduces new features like telemetry, fb_arrary, MP communication sockets, service cores, which requires more internal memory allocation (not everything is from HEAP region but hugepage).
3. rte_pktmbuf_pool_create tries to create (267008 * 2176 + additional place holder) is about 0.8GB.

hence with the above new memory model and services, a total huge page potential shoots over 1GB MMAPED area. Currently, the Huge pages allocated in the system are 512 * 2MB only.

Solutions:

1. reduce the number of MBUF from 267008 to a lower value like 200000 to satisfy the memory requirement.
2. Increase the number of available huge pages from 512 to 600
3. use the new EAL to use `legacy memory, no telemetry, no multiprocess, no service cores`, to reduce memory footprint.
4. use real arg `--socket-mem or -m`, to fix the memory allocations.

Note: the RPM package was not initially housing `libdpdk.pc`. This is required for obtaining platform-specific CFLAGS and LDFLAGS.

Comment: Thanks, Adding the EAL option --legacy-mem solved the issue.